# How to delete from a table when a cursor is found in two other cursors

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, cursor, plsqldeveloper

Below are three different cursors: POTENTIAL_USERS, NO_WORKFLOWS, and NO_MAPPINGS.  I am trying to find a way to delete from the POTENTIAL USERS CURSOR where it is found in the NO_MAPPINGS and also the NO_WORKFLOWS cursors.  I am using cursors because the queries they are referencing are rather long, and this makes it easier for me to follow. Also, the NO_WORKFLOWS and NO_MAPPINGS is referencing two different WITH statements, which I substituted instead of using views because I am in a read-only database, and the POTENTIAL_USERS references a query that pulls out inactive user accounts. I gathered the error messages from creating a similar scenario in another database. I would appreciate any advice or recommendations.

```
  CURSOR USERS_WITHOUT_CHECKEDOUT_WORKFLOWS
  IS
     WITH POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE
          AS (SELECT USER_NAME, USER_ID
                FROM GAI_PM.REP_USERS
               WHERE USER_NAME NOT IN
                        (SELECT USER_NAME
                           FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER ()
                                        OVER (
                                           PARTITION BY REP_USERS.USER_NAME
                                           ORDER BY
                                              TO_DATE (
                                                 SUBSTR (
                                                    LAST_SAVED,
                                                    1,
                                                    10),
                                                 'MM/DD/YYYY') DESC)
                                           RN,
                                        REP_USERS.USER_NAME,
                                        REP_VERSION_PROPS.LAST_SAVED
                                   FROM    GAI_PM.REP_USERS
                                        JOIN
                                           GAI_PM.REP_VERSION_PROPS
                                        ON REP_USERS.USER_ID =
                                              REP_VERSION_PROPS.USER_ID)
                          WHERE RN = 1
                                AND TO_DATE (SUBSTR (LAST_SAVED, 1, 10),
                                             'MM/DD/YYYY') >
                                       ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE), -12))
                     AND UPPER (REP_USERS.USER_NAME) NOT LIKE '%ADMIN%'
                     AND UPPER (REP_USERS.USER_NAME) NOT LIKE
                            '%CSTEINKAMP%'),
          CHECKED_OUT_WORKFLOWS
          AS (SELECT C.SUBJ_NAME,
                     A.TASK_NAME,
                     B.USER_NAME,
                     USER_ID
                FROM GAI_PM.OPB_TASK A
                     JOIN GAI_PM.OPB_USERS B
                        ON A.CHECKOUT_USER_ID = B.USER_ID
                     JOIN GAI_PM.OPB_SUBJECT C
                        ON A.SUBJECT_ID = C.SUBJ_ID
               WHERE A.CHECKOUT_USER_ID <> 0)
     SELECT DISTINCT POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE.USER_NAME
       FROM    POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE
            LEFT JOIN
               CHECKED_OUT_WORKFLOWS
            ON POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE.USER_ID =
                  CHECKED_OUT_WORKFLOWS.USER_ID
      WHERE CHECKED_OUT_WORKFLOWS.USER_NAME IS NULL;

  CURSOR POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE
  IS
     SELECT USER_NAME AS "USERS TO DELETE"
       FROM GAI_PM.REP_USERS
      WHERE USER_NAME NOT IN
               (SELECT USER_NAME
                  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER ()
                               OVER (
                                  PARTITION BY REP_USERS.USER_NAME
                                  ORDER BY
                                     TO_DATE (
                                        SUBSTR (
                                           LAST_SAVED,
                                           1,
                                           10),
                                        'MM/DD/YYYY') DESC)
                                  RN,
                               REP_USERS.USER_NAME,
                               REP_VERSION_PROPS.LAST_SAVED
                          FROM    GAI_PM.REP_USERS
                               JOIN
                                  GAI_PM.REP_VERSION_PROPS
                               ON REP_USERS.USER_ID =
                                     REP_VERSION_PROPS.USER_ID)
                 WHERE RN = 1
                       AND TO_DATE (SUBSTR (LAST_SAVED, 1, 10),
                                    'MM/DD/YYYY') >
                              ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE), -12))
            AND UPPER (REP_USERS.USER_NAME) NOT LIKE '%ADMIN%'
            AND UPPER (REP_USERS.USER_NAME) NOT LIKE '%CSTEINKAMP%';

    BEGIN
     DECLARE
    CURSOR USERS_WITHOUT_CHECKEDOUT_MAPPINGS
     IS
          WITH POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE
              AS (SELECT USER_NAME, USER_ID
                    FROM GAI_PM.REP_USERS
                   WHERE USER_NAME NOT IN
                            (SELECT USER_NAME
                               FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER ()
                                            OVER (
                                               PARTITION BY REP_USERS.USER_NAME
                                               ORDER BY
                                                  TO_DATE (
                                                     SUBSTR (
                                                        LAST_SAVED,
                                                        1,
                                                        10),
                                                     'MM/DD/YYYY') DESC)
                                                RN,
                                            REP_USERS.USER_NAME,
                                           REP_VERSION_PROPS.LAST_SAVED
                                       FROM    GAI_PM.REP_USERS
                                            JOIN
                                               GAI_PM.REP_VERSION_PROPS
                                            ON REP_USERS.USER_ID =
                                                  REP_VERSION_PROPS.USER_ID)
                              WHERE RN = 1
                                    AND TO_DATE (SUBSTR (LAST_SAVED, 1, 10),
                                                 'MM/DD/YYYY') >
                                           ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE), -12))
                         AND UPPER (REP_USERS.USER_NAME) NOT LIKE '%ADMIN%'
                         AND UPPER (REP_USERS.USER_NAME) NOT LIKE
                                '%CSTEINKAMP%'),
              CHECKED_OUT_MAPPINGS
              AS (SELECT C.SUBJ_NAME,
                         A.MAPPING_NAME,
                         B.USER_NAME,
                         B.USER_ID
                    FROM GAI_PM.OPB_MAPPING A
                         JOIN GAI_PM.OPB_USERS B
                            ON A.CHECKOUT_USER_ID = B.USER_ID
                         JOIN GAI_PM.OPB_SUBJECT C
                            ON A.SUBJECT_ID = C.SUBJ_ID
                   WHERE A.CHECKOUT_USER_ID <> 0)
         SELECT DISTINCT POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE.USER_NAME, MAPPING_NAME
           FROM    POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE
                LEFT JOIN
                   CHECKED_OUT_MAPPINGS
                ON POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE.USER_ID =
                      CHECKED_OUT_MAPPINGS.USER_ID
          WHERE CHECKED_OUT_MAPPINGS.USER_NAME IS NULL;


  POTENTIAL_USERS   POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE%ROWTYPE;
  NO_WORKFLOWS      USERS_WITHOUT_CHECKEDOUT_WORKFLOWS%ROWTYPE;
  NO_MAPPINGS       USERS_WITHOUT_CHECKEDOUT_MAPPINGS%ROWTYPE;
 BEGIN
     LOOP
  IF NOT (POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE%ISOPEN)
  THEN
     OPEN POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE;
  END IF;

  IF NOT (USERS_WITHOUT_CHECKEDOUT_WORKFLOWS%ISOPEN)
  THEN
     OPEN USERS_WITHOUT_CHECKEDOUT_WORKFLOWS;
  END IF;

  IF NOT (USERS_WITHOUT_CHECKEDOUT_MAPPINGS%ISOPEN)
  THEN
     OPEN USERS_WITHOUT_CHECKEDOUT_MAPPINGS;
  END IF;

  FETCH POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE INTO POTENTIAL_USERS;

  FETCH USERS_WITHOUT_CHECKEDOUT_WORKFLOWS INTO NO_WORKFLOWS;

  FETCH USERS_WITHOUT_CHECKEDOUT_MAPPINGS INTO NO_MAPPINGS;


        DELETE FROM POTENTIAL_USERS
              WHERE POTENTIAL_USERS.USER_NAME = NO_WORKFLOWS.USER_NAME
                    OR POTENTIAL_USERS.USER_NAME = NO_MAPPINGS.USER_NAME;



  IF (POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE%ISOPEN)
  THEN
     CLOSE POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE;
  END IF;

  IF (USERS_WITHOUT_CHECKEDOUT_WORKFLOWS%ISOPEN)
  THEN
     CLOSE USERS_WITHOUT_CHECKEDOUT_WORKFLOWS;
  END IF;

  IF (USERS_WITHOUT_CHECKEDOUT_MAPPINGS%ISOPEN)
  THEN
     CLOSE USERS_WITHOUT_CHECKEDOUT_MAPPINGS;
  END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
END;
```

These are the error messages I keep getting:

ORA-06550: line 22, column 29:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NO_WORKFLOWS" when expecting one of the following:

(
The symbol "(" was substituted for "NO_WORKFLOWS" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 23, column 3:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "THEN" when expecting one of the following:

) , and or as
The symbol ")" was substituted for "THEN" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 26, column 40:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NO_WORKFLOWS" when expecting one of the following:

(
The symbol "(" was substituted for "NO_WORKFLOWS" to continue.
ORA-06550: line 27, column 44:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "NO_MAPPINGS" when expecting one of the following:

(

Comment: Please edit the question and show how POTENTIAL_USERS, POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE, NO_WORKFLOWS, and NO_MAPPINGS are defined. My initial take on this is that you're trying to use a cursor as you'd use a table, which is not allowed, but I'd like more information so I can show you how to solve the problem rather than just saying "You can't do that". Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized I was making this way too difficult.  All I had to do was split the queries into two separate delete scripts, and then just run each of them separately or as a script.

```
--Finds and deletes users with no access for past year 
--and sees if they have any checked out workflows.

DELETE USER_NAME
  FROM (SELECT USER_NAME
      FROM GAI_PM.REP_USERS
     WHERE USER_NAME NOT IN
              (SELECT USER_NAME
                 FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER ()
                              OVER (
                                 PARTITION BY REP_USERS.USER_NAME
                                 ORDER BY
                                    TO_DATE (
                                       SUBSTR (
                                          LAST_SAVED,
                                          1,
                                          10),
                                       'MM/DD/YYYY') DESC)
                                 RN,
                              REP_USERS.USER_NAME,
                              REP_VERSION_PROPS.LAST_SAVED
                         FROM    GAI_PM.REP_USERS
                              JOIN
                                 GAI_PM.REP_VERSION_PROPS
                              ON REP_USERS.USER_ID =
                                    REP_VERSION_PROPS.USER_ID)
                WHERE RN = 1
                      AND TO_DATE (SUBSTR (LAST_SAVED, 1, 10),
                                   'MM/DD/YYYY') >
                             ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE), -12))
           AND UPPER (REP_USERS.USER_NAME) NOT LIKE '%ADMIN%'
           AND UPPER (REP_USERS.USER_NAME) NOT LIKE '%CSTEINKAMP%') 
 WHERE USER_NAME IN
          (WITH POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE
                AS (SELECT USER_NAME, USER_ID
                      FROM GAI_PM.REP_USERS
                     WHERE USER_NAME NOT IN
                          (SELECT USER_NAME
                             FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER ()
                                          OVER (
                                             PARTITION BY REP_USERS.USER_NAME
                                             ORDER BY
                                                TO_DATE (
                                                   SUBSTR (
                                                      LAST_SAVED,
                                                      1,
                                                      10),
                                                   'MM/DD/YYYY') DESC)
                                             RN,
                                          REP_USERS.USER_NAME,
                                          REP_VERSION_PROPS.LAST_SAVED
                                     FROM    GAI_PM.REP_USERS
                                          JOIN
                                             GAI_PM.REP_VERSION_PROPS
                                          ON REP_USERS.USER_ID =
                                                REP_VERSION_PROPS.USER_ID)
                            WHERE RN = 1
                                  AND TO_DATE (
                                         SUBSTR (LAST_SAVED, 1, 10),
                                         'MM/DD/YYYY') >
                                         ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE),
                                                     -12))
                       AND UPPER (REP_USERS.USER_NAME) NOT LIKE '%ADMIN%'
                       AND UPPER (REP_USERS.USER_NAME) NOT LIKE
                              '%CSTEINKAMP%'),
            CHECKED_OUT_WORKFLOWS
            AS (SELECT C.SUBJ_NAME,
                       A.TASK_NAME,
                       B.USER_NAME,
                       USER_ID
                  FROM GAI_PM.OPB_TASK A
                       JOIN GAI_PM.OPB_USERS B
                          ON A.CHECKOUT_USER_ID = B.USER_ID
                       JOIN GAI_PM.OPB_SUBJECT C
                          ON A.SUBJECT_ID = C.SUBJ_ID
                 WHERE A.CHECKOUT_USER_ID <> 0)
       SELECT DISTINCT POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE.USER_NAME
         FROM    POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE
              LEFT JOIN
                 CHECKED_OUT_WORKFLOWS
              ON POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE.USER_ID =
                    CHECKED_OUT_WORKFLOWS.USER_ID
        WHERE CHECKED_OUT_WORKFLOWS.USER_NAME IS NULL);


--Finds and deletes users with no access for past year 
--and sees if they have any checked out mappings.

DELETE USER_NAME 
  FROM (SELECT USER_NAME
      FROM GAI_PM.REP_USERS
     WHERE USER_NAME NOT IN
              (SELECT USER_NAME
                 FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER ()
                              OVER (
                                 PARTITION BY REP_USERS.USER_NAME
                                 ORDER BY
                                    TO_DATE (
                                       SUBSTR (
                                          LAST_SAVED,
                                          1,
                                          10),
                                       'MM/DD/YYYY') DESC)
                                 RN,
                              REP_USERS.USER_NAME,
                              REP_VERSION_PROPS.LAST_SAVED
                         FROM    GAI_PM.REP_USERS
                              JOIN
                                 GAI_PM.REP_VERSION_PROPS
                              ON REP_USERS.USER_ID =
                                    REP_VERSION_PROPS.USER_ID)
                WHERE RN = 1
                      AND TO_DATE (SUBSTR (LAST_SAVED, 1, 10),
                                   'MM/DD/YYYY') >
                             ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE), -12))
           AND UPPER (REP_USERS.USER_NAME) NOT LIKE '%ADMIN%'
           AND UPPER (REP_USERS.USER_NAME) NOT LIKE '%CSTEINKAMP%')
 WHERE USER_NAME IN
      (WITH POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE
            AS (SELECT USER_NAME, USER_ID
                  FROM GAI_PM.REP_USERS
                 WHERE USER_NAME NOT IN
                          (SELECT USER_NAME
                             FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER ()
                                          OVER (
                                             PARTITION BY REP_USERS.USER_NAME
                                             ORDER BY
                                                TO_DATE (
                                                   SUBSTR (
                                                      LAST_SAVED,
                                                      1,
                                                      10),
                                                   'MM/DD/YYYY') DESC)
                                             RN,
                                          REP_USERS.USER_NAME,
                                          REP_VERSION_PROPS.LAST_SAVED
                                     FROM    GAI_PM.REP_USERS
                                          JOIN
                                             GAI_PM.REP_VERSION_PROPS
                                          ON REP_USERS.USER_ID =
                                                REP_VERSION_PROPS.USER_ID)
                            WHERE RN = 1
                                  AND TO_DATE (
                                         SUBSTR (LAST_SAVED, 1, 10),
                                         'MM/DD/YYYY') >
                                         ADD_MONTHS (TRUNC (SYSDATE),
                                                     -12))
                       AND UPPER (REP_USERS.USER_NAME) NOT LIKE '%ADMIN%'
                       AND UPPER (REP_USERS.USER_NAME) NOT LIKE
                              '%CSTEINKAMP%'),
            CHECKED_OUT_MAPPINGS
            AS (SELECT C.SUBJ_NAME,
                       A.MAPPING_NAME,
                       B.USER_NAME,
                       B.USER_ID
                  FROM GAI_PM.OPB_MAPPING A
                       JOIN GAI_PM.OPB_USERS B
                          ON A.CHECKOUT_USER_ID = B.USER_ID
                       JOIN GAI_PM.OPB_SUBJECT C
                          ON A.SUBJECT_ID = C.SUBJ_ID
                 WHERE A.CHECKOUT_USER_ID <> 0)
       SELECT DISTINCT POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE.USER_NAME
         FROM    POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE
              LEFT JOIN
                 CHECKED_OUT_MAPPINGS
              ON POTENTIAL_USERS_TO_DELETE.USER_ID =
                    CHECKED_OUT_MAPPINGS.USER_ID
        WHERE CHECKED_OUT_MAPPINGS.USER_NAME IS NULL);
```